# Image of the Kummer map for abelian varieties over $p$-adic local fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations

The following statement might be well-known to the community: let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for some prime $p$. Let $A$ be an abelian variety over $K$. Then the image of the Kummer map $A(K)\to H^1(K,T)$, where $T$ is the Tate module of $A$, i.e. $T=\varprojlim_NA[N]$, and $H^1(K,T)$ means the Galois cohomology, coinsides with $H^1_f(K,T)$ in the sense of Bloch--Kato.

In fact this is a statement in a paragraph in the seminal paper of Bloch and Kato. Could anyone direct me to any reference for this statement?

Comment: I'm confused, you ask for a reference and then immediately give the canonical one yourself -- Bloch and Kato give the proof of this in their Examples 3.10 and 3.11. Are you asking for a different reference in addition to this?

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Thanks for pointing it out. I just naively thought that it is a well-known fact to people already so that they just mentioned in the middle of a paragraph. My fault. Thanks again

Comment: The definition of the Bloch--Kato subspace appears for the first time that paper, so its properties could hardly have been "well known already". :-)